# Picklist not showing values

Tags: dependent-picklist

My code is as shown below. I am not getting any error and at the same time am unable to see the output in the 2nd dropdown. So I do not know where the error is!
When I tried hardcoding the cities as shown in this link
http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/10/dependent-picklist-using-apex-in.html
it works. But with the query, its not working.
Pls help.

```
<apex:page controller="TestController_1">

<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputLabel value="State"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>        
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem>                
            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!state}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!states}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="a"/>
            </apex:selectList>                
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputLabel value="City"/>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
        <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!city}" id="a">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!cities}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
    </apex:pageBlockSection>        
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Controller code

```
public class TestController_1
{
public String state {get;set;}
public String city {get;set;}

public List<SelectOption> getStates()
{
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption( ' ' ,'---Select---'));
    for (AggregateResult ar : [
        Select billingcountry n from account where billingcountry!=null group by billingcountry
        ]) 
    {
    String n = (String) ar.get('n');
    options.add(new SelectOption(n, n));
    }
return options;
} 

public List<SelectOption> getCities()
{
    List<SelectOption> stateoptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    stateoptions.add(new SelectOption( ' ' ,'---Select---'));
    for (AggregateResult arstate : [
        Select billingstate s from account where  billingcountry='+state+' and billingstate!=null group by billingstate
        ]) 
    {
    String s = (String) arstate.get('s');
    stateoptions.add(new SelectOption(s, s));
    }
return stateoptions;

}       
}
```

Comment: Instead of rerendering the selectList, try rerendering the pageblockSectionItem or the form itself. Also, add a actionStatus to verify if action is firing or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your cities soql you are comparing billingCountry with state variable. This looks wrong; perhaps the below is better.

```
public List<SelectOption> getCities()
{
    List<SelectOption> stateoptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    stateoptions.add(new SelectOption( ' ' ,'---Select---'));
    for (AggregateResult arstate : [
        Select billingstate s from account where  billingstate='+state+' and billingstate!=null group by billingstate
        ]) 
    {
    String s = (String) arstate.get('s');
    stateoptions.add(new SelectOption(s, s));
    }
return stateoptions;

}
```